# Observable not populating variable

Tags: angular, typescript

My observable is passing back the correct object, but the data is not being stored against a local variable.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { LookupListsService } from '../../services/lookup-lists.service';
import { SexList } from '../../models/lookups/sexType';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})

export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  sexLists: SexList[] = [];

  constructor(private lookupService: LookupListsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getGenderList();
    this.getCountryList();
    this.getSexList(); 
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.classList.add('register-page');
    body.classList.add('off-canvas-sidebar');
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.classList.remove('register-page');
    body.classList.remove('off-canvas-sidebar');
  }
  getSexList(): void {
    this.lookupService.getSexList()
        .subscribe(sexlist => {
            console.log(sexlist)
            this.sexLists = sexlist
        });
  }
}
```

I can see the object in developer tools:

```
{
    "sexList": [
        {
            "sexId": 1,
            "sexCode": 1,
            "sexText": "Male"
        },
        {
            "sexId": 2,
            "sexCode": 2,
            "sexText": "Female"
        }
    ]
}
```

But on my layout I have the following:

```
<div><p>There are: {{sexLists.length}} records in the list</p></div>
```

And I get a undefined in the console for sexLists and my returned text on the page is:

There are: records in the list

I can't figure out why the object never gets set.

Edit added service code:

```
  getSexList(): Observable<SexList[]> {
    var apiURL = this.api.getApiEndPointByName('GetSex');
    console.log(apiURL);
    var sex = this.http.get<SexList[]>(apiURL);
    return sex;
  }
```

Comment: I think you should assign to local variable in a little bit different way. Try to assign: `this.sexLists = sexlist.sexList` as you have object there. And add codepen example please.

Comment: Provide the lookup service. It's difficult to tell what's being emitted by the getSexList() observable without seeing it.

Comment: I used to get this problem, and its something to do with angulars change detection mechanism with local variables in your class... try assigning your ```sexLists``` the ```observable``` itself and then use an ```async``` pipe in your ```html```.

Comment: @MichałTkaczyk you were right. I looked at my API and noticed I was returning the list wrapped in a container. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Caz1224 glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning an object with an array to the component, not the array - I'd suggest "plucking" the array from the response, eg.:

```js
  getSexList(): void {
    this.lookupService.getSexList()
        .pipe(pluck('sexList'))
        .subscribe(sexlist => {
            console.log(sexlist)
            this.sexLists = sexlist
        });
  }
```

(you need to import the `pluck`-operator from RxJs)